# Error in module export with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

I have an issue with exporting a module in Node.js.
Here is a part of my code:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var module = require('module');

var DeviceRequester = function(port, name)
{
   ...   
};

var SMValueGetter = function(socket)
{
   ...
};

module.exports.DeviceRequester = DeviceRequester;
module.exports.SMValueGetter = SMValueGetter;
```

When I use it I get the following error:

```
module.exports.DeviceRequester = DeviceRequester;
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'DeviceRequester' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (<PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/lse/lib/lse.js:168:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (<PROJECT_PATH>/server.js:6:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

I have no idea why it occurs. I've red the Node.js documentation and some tutorials about exporting modules and all of them do it that way. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: tried another name just as 'mymodule' ? i think you are overwriting the default `module` ..

Comment: oops, yes, that's the answer, @GeoPhoenix.

Comment: When I rename `var module = = require('module');` and use `mymodule.exports.DeviceRequester = DeviceRequester; mymodule.exports.SMValueGetter = SMValueGetter;`,I still get the same error. When I use just `exports.DeviceRequester = DeviceRequester` without `module/mymodule` it works.

Comment: why are you using `mymodule.exports`.. ? the common way of exporting variables is `module.exports` and not `yourmodule.exports`..

Comment: What you should do is `var your module = require('module')`, not what you assign to.

Comment: I've understood your answare wrong :D Not it works. Great. Big thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give more attentions at errors

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'DeviceRequester' of undefined`

at line `var module=require("module");` you are overwriting the default `module` variable.

simple try to change at something that makes more sense, such as

`var MyModule=require(..path..)`

Comment: that's because you haven't fully understand what `module` variable is .. `exports.VAR` is a short way of exporting variable that use `module.exports`

Comment: @DavidBulczak, you renamed the wrong part (according to the "above").

Comment: I think that I understand the Node.js module system a little bit more :) Thank you guys!